# Build Cordova iOS app for Generic Build from CLI

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a custom Cordova iOS Plugin, which uses camera functionality. It does not supports simulator. However, it can be built for Device or Generic iOS device.

Now, after adding the iOS plugin, to a demo app, I would like to run cordova command to build it for Generic iOS Device.

```
//Builds for Device
cordova build ios --device

//Builds for Simulator
cordova build ios
```

Digging a little, I found a command

```
xcodebuild -destination generic/platform=iOS
```

Source: [Link](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xcodebuild-destination-options/)

Question: How do I build cordova app for Generic iOS platform from CLI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use XCode after running these. Also - you are using the PhoneGap Build tag and this is not a PGB question.

Comment: That's the thing. I need to do this via the terminal. And Cordova build ios will fail, because by default Cordova points to simulator. Also, since Cordova and phonegap are similar I added the tag

Comment: You misunderstood. PGB works in a different way. PG and Cordova are both CLI run